# Annoying error: expected class name before '{' token

Tags: c++, oop, compiler-errors, arduino

I've been trying to compile a basic program using a library for arduino and I keep getting this expected class name before '{' token error. I am novice to c++, so detailed explanation/drop-in solution is much appreciated.

Here is the code :

**SerialGSM.h**

```
#ifndef _SerialGSM_H
#define _SerialGSM_H
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define SERIALTIMEOUT 2000
#define PHONESIZE 13
#define MAXMSGLEN 160

class SerialGSM : public SoftwareSerial {
public:
  SerialGSM(int rxpin,int txpin);
  void FwdSMS2Serial();
  void SendSMS();
  void SendSMS(char * cellnumber,char * outmsg);
  void DeleteAllSMS();
  void Reset();
  void EndSMS();
  void StartSMS();
  int ReadLine();
  int ReceiveSMS();
  void Verbose(boolean var1);
  boolean Verbose();
  void Sender(char * var1);
  char * Sender();
  void Rcpt(char * var1);
  char * Rcpt();
  void Message(char * var1);
  char * Message();
  void Boot();

  boolean verbose;
  char sendernumber[PHONESIZE + 1];
  char rcpt[PHONESIZE + 1];
  char outmessage[160];
  char inmessage[160];

protected:
  unsigned long lastrec;

};

#endif /* not defined _SerialGSM_H */
```

**SerialGSM.cpp**

```
// SerialGSM version 1.1
// by Meir Michanie
// meirm@riunx.com





// error codes
// http://www.developershome.com/sms/resultCodes2.asp
#include <SerialGSM.h>

SerialGSM::SerialGSM(int rxpin,int txpin):
SoftwareSerial(rxpin,txpin)
{
 verbose=false;
}

void SerialGSM::FwdSMS2Serial(){
  Serial.println("AT+CMGF=1"); // set SMS mode to text
  this->println("AT+CMGF=1"); // set SMS mode to text
  delay(200);
  this->ReadLine();
  Serial.println("AT+CNMI=3,3,0,0"); // set module to send SMS data to serial out upon receipt 
  this->println("AT+CNMI=3,3,0,0"); // set module to send SMS data to serial out upon receipt 
  delay(200);
  this->ReadLine();
}

void SerialGSM::SendSMS(char * cellnumber,char * outmsg){
  this->Rcpt(cellnumber);
  if (verbose) Serial.println(rcpt);
  this->StartSMS();
  this->Message(outmsg);
  Serial.print(outmessage);
  this->print(outmessage);
  this->EndSMS();
  delay(500);
  this->ReadLine();
}

void SerialGSM::SendSMS(){
  if (verbose) Serial.println(rcpt);
  if (verbose) Serial.println(outmessage);
  this->StartSMS();
  Serial.print(outmessage);
  this->print(outmessage);
  this->EndSMS();
  delay(500);
  this->ReadLine();
}

void SerialGSM::DeleteAllSMS(){
  Serial.println("AT+CMGD=1,4"); // delete all SMS
  this->println("AT+CMGD=1,4"); // delete all SMS
  delay(200);
  this->ReadLine();
}

void SerialGSM::Reset(){
  Serial.println("AT+CFUN=1,1"); // Reset Modem
  this->println("AT+CFUN=1,1"); // Reset Modem
  delay(200);
  this->ReadLine();
}


void SerialGSM::EndSMS(){
  this->print(char(26));  // ASCII equivalent of Ctrl-Z
  Serial.println();

  //delay(5 * 1000); // the SMS module needs time to return to OK status
}

void SerialGSM::StartSMS(){

  Serial.println("AT+CMGF=1"); // set SMS mode to text
  this->println("AT+CMGF=1"); // set SMS mode to text
  delay(200);
  this->ReadLine();

  Serial.print("AT+CMGS=");
  this->print("AT+CMGS=");

  this->print(char(34)); // ASCII equivalent of "

  Serial.print(rcpt);
  this->print(rcpt);

  this->println(char(34));  // ASCII equivalent of "

  delay(500); // give the module some thinking time
  this->ReadLine();

}

int SerialGSM::ReadLine(){
  static int pos=0;
  char nc;
  while (this->available()){
    nc=this->read();
    if (nc == '\n' or (pos > MAXMSGLEN) or ((millis()> lastrec + SERIALTIMEOUT)and (pos > 0)) ){
      nc='\0';
      lastrec=millis();
      inmessage[pos]=nc;
     pos=0;
     if (verbose) Serial.println(inmessage);
      return 1;
    }
    else if (nc=='\r') {
    }
    else{
      inmessage[pos++]=nc;
      lastrec=millis();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}


int SerialGSM::ReceiveSMS(){
  static boolean insms=0;
  if (this->ReadLine()){
  // Get the number of the sms sender in order to be able to reply
    if ( strstr(inmessage, "CMT: ") != NULL ){
        insms=1;
        int sf=6;
        if(strstr(inmessage, "+CMT:")) sf++; 
            for (int i=0;i < PHONESIZE;i++){
              sendernumber[i]=inmessage[sf+i];
            }
        sendernumber[PHONESIZE]='\0';
        return 0;
     }else{ 
        if(insms) {
            insms=0;
            return 1;
        }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}


boolean SerialGSM::Verbose(){
    return verbose;
}

void SerialGSM::Verbose(boolean var1){
    verbose=var1;
}

char * SerialGSM::Sender(){
    return sendernumber;
}


char * SerialGSM::Rcpt(){
    return rcpt;
}

char * SerialGSM::Message(){
    return inmessage;
}


void SerialGSM::Sender(char * var1){
    sprintf(sendernumber,"%s",var1);
}


void SerialGSM::Rcpt(char * var1){
    sprintf(rcpt,"%s",var1);
}

void SerialGSM::Message(char * var1){
    sprintf(outmessage,"%s",var1);
}

void SerialGSM::Boot(){
  int counter=0;
  while(counter++ < 15){
    if (verbose) Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }
  if (verbose) Serial.println();

}
```

**Arduino sketch**

```
#include <SerialGSM.h>
SerialGSM cell(2,3);

boolean sendonce=true;
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // cell.begin(9600);
  cell.Verbose(true);
  cell.Boot();
  cell.DeleteAllSMS();
  cell.FwdSMS2Serial();
 }


void loop(){
  if (cell.ReceiveSMS()){
     Serial.print("Sender: ");
     Serial.println(cell.Sender());
     Serial.print("message: ");
     Serial.println(cell.Message());
     cell.DeleteAllSMS();
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Here's complete error message :
/home/agt/arduino/libraries/SerialGSM.h:10: error : expected class-name before '{' token
Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting this error?  Can you please show us more context from the error message?

Comment: Refrain from using `_SerialGSM_H`, as identifiers starting with `_<capital>` are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Please post the **exact** error message, including source file name and line number,  *in the question*. Thanks.

Comment: where is the error? @user2016452

Comment: SoftwareSerial is within a namespace?

Comment: @Lieuwe that'd be a good stab at it.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49538/arduino is a site proposal for a Arduino specific Q&A site. You could help to bring it alive by supporting it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting up a mutual inclusion between your header files "arduino.h" and "serialgsm.h". Resolve that by using forward declarations and the error will most likely disappear (or you will at least get a different one).

Comment: Hello, adding #include <SoftwareSerial.h> in Arduino sketch did the trick, thanks :)